# How to create VM in azure from disk using python

Tags: python, azure, cloud

I want to create Linux VM from a disk in azure using **python**.

I have referred the **azure-sdk-for-python**, but i did not find the solution for this. Can anyone explain me the procedure please.

I have found this when I searched on google :

image_name = '{}-osImage'.format(vmname)

async_create = self.compute_client.images.create_or_update(
        resource_group,
 image_name,

```
    {
            'location': location,
            'storage_profile': {
                 'os_disk': {
                        'os_type': 'Linux',
                        'os_state': "Generalized",
                        'blob_uri': image,
                        'caching': "ReadWrite",
                 }
             }
    })
```

managed_image_ref = async_create.result()

image_reference = ImageReference(id = managed_image_ref.id)

storage_profile = StorageProfile(image_reference = image_reference)

I know this :
1. One can create VM from an image
2. For creating VM from disk, one has to do it using VHD.
But I do not know how to proceed in this (especially using python).
I am new to azure and do not know much about the VHDs. So please explain me the flow also.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Your disk is a VHD or a  managed disk?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT managed disk.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT please help me with this.

Comment: Now, I know how to do this. You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49068135/create-vm-on-azure-with-custom-image-using-python/49102602#49102602). The id is your managed disk resource id.