# Create VM on Azure with custom image using python

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine

Launching a VM using a marketplace image in Azure is pretty straight forward.

here is the relevant piece of code.

def create_vm(network_client, compute_client):

```
vm_parameters = {
    'storage_profile': {
        'image_reference': {
            'publisher': 'MicrosoftWindowsServer',
            'offer': 'WindowsServer',
            'sku': '2012-R2-Datacenter',
            'version': 'latest'
        }
    },

vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.create_or_update(
    GROUP_NAME, 
    VM_NAME, 
    vm_parameters
)
```

(Clearly there is more in the actual code, this is the part that I think is most relevant)

So in this case the image reference points to the marketplace.

I used the following doc to create a custom image.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-generalized-managed?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json

I would like to create a VM based on the new custom image that I created. It is my perception that image_reference should point to something else but it isn't clear to me what it should be. Can anybody help here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, Azure Python SDK uses Azure Rest API. You could check this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/createorupdate#create_a_vm_from_a_custom_image.).

So, you could modify your script like below:

```
vm_parameters = {
    'storage_profile': {
        'image_reference': {
            'id' : '/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/myResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/{existing-custom-image-name}'
        }
    },
```

Comment: That did it! Is this documented somewhere? I wasn't able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: You could check this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.compute.v2017_12_01.models.imagereference?view=azure-python

Comment: In fact, the parameters is a json file. Azure rest api body also requires a json file. When you don't know how to structure parameters, you could check Azure rest api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/